# Find the largest positive value of $x$ at which the curve $y = (2x + 7)^6 (x - 2)^5$ has a horizontal tangent line.

Tags: calculus

I need help with the following question.

Find the largest positive value of x at which the curve:

$$y = (2x + 7)^6 (x - 2)^5$$

has a horizontal tangent line.

Comment: Hint: Horizontal tangent line - is $\frac{dy}{dx} 0, $ or positive or negative?

Comment: A sketch often helps - easy to do here by first sketching the sextic and quintic factors.

Comment: How do I proceed after finding the derivative of y?

Answer (score 4):

To solve $y'(x)=0$ when $y(x)\ne0$, one can consider  the derivative $\dfrac{y'(x)}{y(x)}$ of the function $\log|y(x)|=6\log|2x+7|+5\log|x-2|$. The computations become much simpler since
$$
\frac{y'(x)}{y(x)}=\frac{6\cdot2}{2x+7}+\frac5{x-2}.
$$
Thus, $y'(x)=0$ as soon as the RHS is zero, that is, when $12(x-2)+5(2x+7)=0$, that is, when $x=-\frac12$. Complete the reasoning with the values where $y(x)=0$, that is, $x=-\frac72$ and $x=2$.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, really makes the computation much simpler.

Comment: @Didier Can I find you in the chat?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  what slope corresponds to a horizontal tangent?  How do you find the slope of a tangent line?

Comment: Am I on the right track to first find the derivative of y? What do I do next?

Comment: @Xavier:  Yes, you are on the right track.  As Kirthi says, you want the derivative to be zero, as that is the slope of the tangent.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\displaystyle{\frac{dy}{dx} = \left(12(2x+7)^5(x-2)^5+5(2x+7)^6(x-2)^4 \right) = 0}$ , in other words

$\displaystyle{\frac{dy}{dx} = (2x+7)^5(x-2)^4(22x+11) = 0}$ at what points?

$\displaystyle{\frac{dy}{dx} = 0}$ at $x=-\frac{7}{2}, x=2, x=-\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Hi, shouldn't the derivative be 12(2x+7)^5(x-2)^5 + 5(x-2)^4(2x+7)^6 ? Taking into account of chain-rule. Do correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Xavier: You are correct.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126: Thanks. Do you have any idea how to proceed from there?

Comment: @Xavier, corrected that but the approach is still the same. (I just gave a hint)